# Distracting Exception output in QtCreator when debugging Windows application

Tags: windows, debugging, qt-creator, windbg

I am using QtCreator 4.1rc1 under Windows with the msvc tool chain. The debugger is cdb from the Windows 8.1 SDK. I had the same issue with older versions of QtCreator.

When I debug my application, then there are many messages to the output (and issues) pane in the form

*Exception at 0x773596c2, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in WinSCard!SCardTransmit*

I understand, that this is to be expected under Windows and those exceptions are actually not a problem. But they pollute the output and issues pane and basically render them useless.

So I tried to get rid of the messages. **But failed after hours trying.** What I tried is the following:

- Use the check box 'Ignore first chance access violation' under Tools->Options->Debugger->CDB
- Specifying command line arguments to cdb.exe: -xi
- Create a script file for cdb.exe to be used at startup to avoid the warnings. The script contained the commands 'SXI 8010000a; SXI 0000071a; SXI e06d7363'. I tried placing the script in several directories and also specifying it with the command line options -cf or -cfr.

When I run cdb.exe from a command line using the startup script, it works! No exceptions are printed to the console. But when I start it from QtCreator, they are there again. 
I assume, that QtCreator is using their own startup scripts and those overwrite the ones I specified.

Has anyone succeeded in hiding those exception outputs under QtCreator with cdb?

Comment: You're probably right WinDbg workspaces do not apply to cdb. Sorry.